Why does take(n) used on an istream_view cause it to skip the next token in C++20?
In C++20, when I use std::ranges::views::take() on a std::ranges::istream_view(), the next token in the istream_view after iterating the take view is skipped.
Consider the following C++20 code snippet:
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace rn = std::ranges;

int main() {
    std::string input = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
    std::istringstream input_stream(input);

    std::vector<int> head;
    rn::copy(rn::istream_view<int>(input_stream) | rn::views::take(5),
             std::back_inserter(head));

    int next_int = 0;
    input_stream >> next_int;

    for(auto x : head) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << next_int << std::endl;
}

When I compile and run this code in g++14 or clang++17, the following output is produced (notice the missing "6"):
1 2 3 4 5 7

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/vdGvx9666
Why does this happen? Is this the intended behaviour? What can be done to work around this?

This is a well-known issue for Ranges.

The problem is how input iterators and input ranges defined/handled in C++. C++26 views::cache_last and its reference implementation cache1 in ranges-v3 can help. But you need to keep the istream_view instance. The std::istream object has already consumed its one past the end character.

This looks like shortcoming of std::ranges::copy.
Note that return value of it is:
std::ranges::copy, std::ranges::copy_if, std::ranges::copy_result, std::ranges::copy_if_result - cppreference.com

Return value
A ranges::in_out_result containing an input iterator equal to last and an output iterator past the last element copied.

Now in your case input iterator type is std::ranges::istream_view and this thing to point after last element copied it have to read (consume) next element. This is necessary to detect if current iterator reached end (of stream).
So to get return value of std::ranges::copy iterator std::ranges::istream_view must be progress beyond last element and read next one leading to problem you are osberving.
Note that old fashion std::copy_n is  defined in different way to prevent this problem: note "possible implementation" increases input iterator ins strange way and the fact that input iterator is not returned.

Thank you for mentioning std::copy_n! I tried it with an istream_iterator instead of the ranges approach and it does work: https://godbolt.org/z/jrxdqP4s8 . This is a good workaround.
Using the ranges version of copy_n, std::ranges::copy_n, however, seems to have the same problem as using std::ranges::copy with std::ranges::views::take: https://godbolt.org/z/x5xsenx9o .
